# Compare cell by cell in column is substring of inputed string

Tags: python

I have excel file which has two column with name "CODE1" & "RESULT".

I want when user input a string on screen, it will check in "CODE1" column to find out cell string which is substring of inputted string.. then it will return the string at "RESULT" column.

```
The excel format as below

CODE1      RESULT

excel      OK.. Excel
Outlook    OK... Outlook
Skype      OK... Skype
```

When user input string: "I want to ask a question about excel"

Then the program will check , compare and return result : "OK...Excel"

The code which I used as below :

```
path_to_csv_file = 'C:\\names.xlsx'
code_names_dataframe = pd.read_excel(path_to_csv_file) 
code_names_dictionary = code_names_dataframe.to_dict(orient='records')
user_response = input()
while True:  
    name = None 
    username = user_response
        if code_name['CODE1'] in username:
            name = code_name['RESULT']
```

This code run and show warning: TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not float

Comment: What is `code_name`? Please share a complete, working example.

Comment: pls check as above

Comment: "pls" run your own code and find that it doesn't work. I'm guessing `code_name` is a broken reference to `code_names_dictionary`?

Comment: hi Bro.. I want to check if cell contain substring which include in a string when user input into the screen. How to do that ?